# How to prevent parameter tampering of the data being passed from React JS to Express Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have an application that has Express as its back-end and React for the front-end.

I am trying to pass a POST request data using axios from React JS to my Express application.
The request data are ALL based on user-input from the form I have created in React.
*(Sample fields include: "contactNo","amountToDonate", etc.)*

When Express receives the data from React, Express would then make another axios POST request to a different third-party application.

How do I make sure that my application is safe from parameter tampering?

I have watched a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOLubxfJUnU) regarding web parameter tampering, and he showed that he can modify the request data from the client to send to the server. I do not want this happening especially when all the user input data are somehow sensitive information.

I tried installing the Burp Suite application, as seen in the video, myself and tried altering all the data from the request, and they are still successfully being sent to Express, and even getting a success response from the third-party server.

I have already added type-checks in my codes. However, when the original and modified values are of the same type, i.e. same integer modifying *amountToDonate* value from **500** to **10**, I am not sure how to validate for this. I'm stuck.

Comment: You use SSL. If the data is really important, use client certificates.

Comment: You can prevent other users tampering or employing some sort of man-in-the-middle attack by using SSL.
However, you can't prevent a technical savvy user visiting your site from tampering the data he/she is sending to your server. The solution is never trust data received from users, always treat it as being possibly malicious and perform validation server side. 

When integrating with 3rd payment provider like paypal to process donation, read their security guidelines to perform validation.

Comment: Do you mean I should encrypt my request data in React using some OpenSSL algorithm then decrypt it in my Express app?